# Clustering via Max-Cut

Tags: graphs, machine-learning, clustering

I wonder if there are papers that uses max cut algorithm(s) to cluster data. For example, if an edge between two nodes $u$ and $v$ indicate that $u$ and $v$ are different, then the max-cut in some sense partition the data into two clusters in a meaningful way.

Comment: Usually you want to cut as few edges as possible, so *min cut* or *sparsest cut* seems more appropriate.

Comment: And you usually have edges between nodes that are _similar_ and not _different_.  Then you get back the classic clustering problem.

Comment: Max-cut for general graphs is known to be $\text{NP-Complete}$. So usually, when people use graph-cuts to cluster data into two parts, they tend to use an "energy function" that penalize dividing the graph at certain points. Graph-cuts (with max-flow min-cut) are used a lot in Computer Graphics and Computer Vision for example. Here is one example for such use: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/iccv01.pdf ("Interactive Graph Cuts
for Optimal Boundary & Region Segmentation of Objects in N-D
Images")

Comment: I am aware of min cut formulation. However, I was wondering if there are applications where the notion of being "different" instead of being "similar", represented by graphs, is easier to see in the data.